# My understanding of `set --` wrong?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I expect

```
set -- "a b"
```

to set `$1 = "a"` and `$2 = "b"`, but instead it's setting `$1 = "a b"` and `$2 = ""` what gives?

Comment: "What gives"? Well, you provided one argument. That's what gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double quotes indicate that `"a b"` should be treated as a single parameter.  Use

```
set -- a b
```

to treat them as two parameters.

**Edit in response to your comment**: Like this?

```
$ a="a b"
$ set -- $a
$ echo $1
a
$ echo $2
b
```

Comment: Thanks, so is it possible to set a variable to "a b" and then use set -- to get a and b out separately?

Comment: @JamieKitson: Answered above due to limitation of comment formatting.

Comment: Limitation? `a="a b"; set -- $a; echo $1; echo $2;`

Comment: Sorry, I can see what I was doing now, I did set -- $(echo $a), I should get some sleep.

Comment: @JamieKitson, this is exactly the exception to the rule "always quote your variables" -- in this case you *want* the 'word splitting' behaviour of unquoted variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

A quoted string is a single "word", so you simply need:

```
$ set -- "a" "b"
```